# PDO usa sintaxe de algum SGBD ou funcionam todas?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Quando se considera **o uso do PDO**, uma das principais usabilidades é a abrangência de **vários bancos de dados**.

---

###Cenário exemplo

Formas diferentes para se filtrar 5 registros, que variam conforme o banco de dados:

```
SELECT TOP 5 campo FROM tabela

SELECT campo FROM tabela LIMIT 5

SELECT campo FROM
(SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY campo)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

---

###Dúvidas

- PDO tem um "padrão" mais parecido com algum banco em específico?
- Quando utilizo PDO, posso usar qualquer uma das formas acima que irá "converter" conforme o banco?
- Quando eu "mudo" meu banco de dados, teria que alterar todas queries, ou o PDO faz isso automático?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL; DR

Você tem que reescrever "todas" as *queries*.

## Detalhando

Você acabou de perguntar sobre a falácia do PDO. Ele é um mecanismo de abstração à API de acesso ao banco de dados, e não dos comandos do banco de dados.

Um dos motivos das pessoas usarem PDO é poder um dia trocar de banco de dados. E essa já é uma falácia. As pessoas não fazem isso. Elas criam uma complicação para algo que tem chance quase zero de acontecer. E se acontecer o custo de adaptação é absurdamente maior do que o acesso à API. E se for o banco de dados o problema então é provável que terá que trocar outras coisas. Decisões erradas quase nunca vêm sozinhas. Em muitos casos tem que trocar até a linguagem.

Fora os casos extremos é uma questão de *tuning* adequado do DB do que trocá-lo. Tem exemplos de sites enormes usando todos os DBs, até mesmo SQLite, então trocar o DB raramente será a solução, e se precisar mesmo, é uma mudança tão radical de perfil de site que mudar tudo não será problema.

Mas o que mais as pessoas não enxergam é que os comandos SQL a serem usados, e até a modelagem da base de dados tem que ser diferente de acordo com o SGDB escolhido. A pior coisa que você pode fazer é usar um modelo pensando para o MySQL e mudar para o Oracle, e usar as *queries* de um no outro, porque mesmo que funcione, terão comprometimentos diferentes e o resultado será pior.

Você continuará precisando mandar os comandos específicos de cada banco de dados. Ele não irá converter qualquer coisa, não interpretará o que escreveu nas consultas e comandos enviados ao servidor, não te ajudará em nada.

Não dá para dizer que terá que mudar todas *queries*, mas se tiver sorte terá. Sim, sorte, porque fará você repensar todo o sistema e isso será muito bom. Azar se achar que facilitou sua vida.

E nem falei quando a mudança da persistência não é só mudar do MySQL para o SQL Server, mas de todo o modelo de dados que sequer mantém o relacional. Se a decisão do DB foi errada é provável que só conserte de verdade com troca total do modelo.

Outro motivo das pessoas escolherem PDO é a segurança. Aí é só desinformação. Não há motivos para ele ser mais seguro. Indiretamente pode ser até mais inseguro.

Já vi gente dizendo que é mais rápido, é raro, mas tem quem fale. Não tem como uma camada extra ser mais rápida que a original.

Então quase sempre a escolha pelo seu uso é equivocado. Não estou dizendo que não tenha algum caso para uso, mas é muito raro ele ser necessário e útil.

E se prepare que ele tem várias desvantagens também, mas isso está fora do escopo da pergunta.

Que eu saiba não tem nada que faça a abstração que deseja, e mesmo que tenha é impossível ter algo com bom resultado. Já tentaram em outras linguagens, equipes muito capacitadas fizeram de tudo, evoluíram, e ainda atende mais ou menos bem uma parcela dos casos, o resto atende mal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A "vantagem" do PDO em poder ser usado com diversos bancos, então não seria a "troca" de banco (o que é raro como disse), mas sim a possibilidade de trabalhar com diversos bancos, e assim "unificar" todo um "sistema", como por exemplo, um sistema específico que coleta dados de diversos sistemas, e os processa para outro fim!?

Comment: Pode ser visto desta forma, mas quase sempre se trabalhar com vários também é um erro de arquitetura. Mas mesmo que tenha, provavelmente por legado, ter que acessar DBs diferentes, o PDO ainda não é útil porque cada operação acessará um banco e você sabe qual é, não precisa dele. O mesmo problema da troca vale pra um sistema universal, o acesso teria que ser mais especializado, não tem como escapar disso. Pra falar a verdade todo uso do PDO é por preguiça e/ou desconhecimento.

Comment: É como o pessoal usar GUI web pra universalizar. Fica ruim, tem várias desvantagens, mas o pessoal acha que assim está ganhando produtividade. Sim, no curto prazo, no longo será pior. Uso do PDO é essencialmente um *hoax*.

Comment: Entendi! O contexto que tenho é um sistema de processamento de informações de todos os outros sistemas de uma empresa. Ele irá coletar todos os dados dos outros e trazer dados processados específicos. A ideia do PDO seria criar funções padrões de processamento, onde eu teria "consultas em comum", mas com bancos diferentes, então a única coisa que mudaria seria a query, assim teria uma função que só preciso passar diferente a query, e o resto do processamento ficaria igual. Assim não preciso de 1 função pra cada tipo de banco. A ideia era essa, por isso a pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: Esse pode ser um caso útil, mas só entendendo o caso mais profundamente pra afirmar. Por outro lado talvez essa função seja justamente o que o PDO faz, aí volta não fazer sentido, ou seja, o PDO é útil quando criará algo que o PDO já faz, vira um paradoxo.

Comment: Mas ele não faz a "conversão" de sintaxe, somente a execução em diversos banco. O que estou enxergando é que a única coisa que muda é a sintaxe, o resto é padrão (conexão, bind, etc).

Comment: Esse "só" é também conhecido como "tudo o que importa"

Comment: Amigo @Maniero, permita-me não discordar, mas questionar sua resposta, já que esse é o propósito deste site. Acredito que na documentação oficial do PHP está bem claro o que o PDO é e não é, então o primeiro parágrafo da sua resposta está perfeito.

Comment: @Maniero, sobre o segundo parágrafo, na documentação está "PDO does not provide a database abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing feature". Então se existem pessoas que o utilizam para portar a aplicação de um SGBD para outro, estão utilizando da maneira errada. No meu entendimento, a escolha pelo PDO é por uma questão de praticidade (não preguiça). Vocẽ pode trabalhar em um projeto com MySQL, em outro com PostgreSQL, outro em Oracle, Sybase, SQLite, etc., e sempre utilizar o PDO. A longo prazao a curva de aprendizado é menor para o programador.

Comment: Obviamente cada SGBD tem suas particularidades. 

Sobre segurança, acredito que esta deve ser feito em camadas, e o uso de Prepared Statements adicionam uma boa camada de segurança na aplicação, e o PDO tem suporte e você não precisa ficar aprendendo como funcionam prepared statements em diferentes tipos de conexão, aprende uma vez.

Acredito ainda que existem outros benefícios, como o controle de erros através de exceções. Muito mais prático utilizar um try catch do que vários if else.

Comment: Enfim, resumidamente, acredito que o uso do PDO é por estes benefícios, e não para portar SGDBs. Para quem está aprendendo PHP agora, eu encorajaria o seu uso, sua utilização é bastante simples, não traz nenhuma complexidade extra para o projeto. A performance e estabilidade são excelentes. Eu mesmo nunca me deparei com um erro oriundo do PDO.

Comment: @PauloSakamoto Curva de aprendizado é boa no curto prazo. Você tem razão no que diz, o PDO não provê o que as pessoas acham que ele provê )portabilidade), por isso digo que ele é um *hoax*. E o que ele provê de verdade não é algo necessário. É uma facilidade muito pequena pra justificar sua adoção, que tem um custo. Os recursos nativos tem tudo o que o PDO tem e do jeito certo, o PDO faz errado. pra mim exceção é o goto do século XXI, quase ninguém sabe fazer certo, então melhor ficar longe disso. E em linguagem de *script*  faz pouco sentido de qualquer forma. Vc **pode** usar certo, outros ñ

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com este ["Artigo"](https://www.devmedia.com.br/biblioteca-pdo-php/24015)

> [...] PDO, não gera comandos SQL dinamicamente, então, não adianta
> você utilizar algum comando SQL especifico do SQL Server e, depois,
> mudar para MySQL. Neste caso seria necessário alterar este comando.

Logo o PDO apenas executa o comando dado por você, sendo que tal comando precisa estar no padrão do banco de dados escolhido.